# Meson: add include directory to target located within build folder

Tags: c++, meson-build

I am trying to build a c++ shared library using the meson build system. I have basically 2 directories `$ROOT/src/` and `$ROOT/tests/` in which I put all source / header and test files, respectively.

A minimal build script for that could be (ignoring meson.build files in sub-directories, which essentially just populate the lists *sourceFiles* and *testFiles*)

```py
project(
  'soLibProject',
  'cpp'
)

# get source files in src/ sub-directory
sourceFiles = []
subdir('src/')

# get test files in tests/ sub-directory
testFiles = []
subdir('tests/')

# build shared library
so_lib = shared_library(
  'soLib',
  sourceFiles
)

# build test executable
tests = executable(
  'tests',
  testFiles,
  link_with: so_lib
)
```

Building the shared library works fine, and I can get the test to work by forming relative paths to the header files inside the `$ROOT/src/` directory. What I am currently trying to do, however, is to construct a folder which contains all header files from the `$ROOT/src/**` directory and another, automatically generated header file, which includes those header files. That part is easy, however, I decided to place that header directory (essentially the `include/` directory as it will be later used for the library) inside the build root, i.e. if I run `meson build/debug`, then I am doing something like `cp $ROOT/src/**/*.hpp $ROOT/build/debug/include/`. If I want to use those header files instead for my tests, I have to include that directory in the `executable` target using `include_directories:` , however, I can't use `meson.build_root() + 'include/'` as that is an absolute path (and we can only use relative path for meson). I should mention here that the build directory does not need to be `build/debug` and there are user-defined targets so I can not know in advance all possible build directories.

So I guess my question would be either how to get a relative path to the build directory (ideally in *the meson way*, i.e. I know that I can run external commands or python scripts to do some magic, I am just wondering if there is a cleaner solution than that available) or how I can instruct meson to look for a folder named `include/` within the build directory (I know that the build directory is automatically included in meson's search path)

Comment: Have a look into `install_headers` whether this feature suits your needs.

Comment: I don't think this would work / be practical. I am writing a library so don't want to abuse any of the install commands for my needs (that should be there only for installing the library). But even if I were to use that, I would still need to set the prefix dynamically based on the changing build directory.